# A confusing vector field differential

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

In my notes on theoretical mechanics, I wrote that my professor stated this vector identity:

$$\mathrm{d}\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{r})=[\nabla\cdot\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{r})] \mathbf{dr} + [\nabla\times\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{r})]\times\mathbf{dr}$$

Here, $\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{r})$ stands for the vector field depending only on the position vector $\mathbf{r}$. In other words, it's a vector-valued function of a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

The thing is, I didn't manage to write down what the importance was, although I think it had something to do with separating parallel and perpendicular differential vectors.

I tried to find something like this on the Internet and I also tried to show it, but I'm afraid I can't find an elegant way to show this and I don't think I'll gain anything by mechanically grinding it out.

What is the significance of this identity? Is there a simple way to prove it?

Comment: Should we interpret $\mathbf r$ as being the position of some object, and that position depends on a lot of different variables?

Comment: Yes, it's a position vector of a classical particle, I'll edit my question to make it more clear :)

Answer (score 1):

Curious formula, I'm not sure I've seen this before. That said, let's have a go at it.

Let $\vec{P} = \langle \ A, \ B, \ C  \ \rangle$ and suppose $\vec{dr} = \langle dx,dy,dz \rangle$. The total differential of the vector field is:
\begin{align} 
d\vec{P} 
&= \langle \ dA, \ dB, \ dC  \ \rangle  \\ 
&= \langle \ A_xdx+A_ydy+A_zdz, \ B_xdx+B_ydy+B_zdz, \ C_xdx+C_ydy+C_zdz  \ \rangle  \\ 
&= (A_x+B_y+C_z ) \langle dx, dy, dz \rangle -\langle B_ydx+C_zdx,A_xdy+C_zdy,A_xdz+B_ydz \rangle 
\\ 
& \qquad + \langle \ A_ydy+A_zdz, \ B_xdx+B_zdz, \ C_xdx+C_ydy  \ \rangle   \\ 
&= (\nabla \cdot \vec{P}) \vec{dr} + \langle  A_ydy+A_zdz-B_ydx-C_zdx,  B_xdx+B_zdz-A_xdy-C_zdy, \ \ \ \ \ \ \qquad C_xdx+C_ydy-A_xdz-B_ydz  \rangle   \\
\end{align}
Well, I must go eat supper, but I think we see where this is going. It was delicious, and now we continue, let's study the curl term
\begin{align} 
[\nabla \times \vec{P}] \times \vec{dr}
&= \langle C_y-B_z, A_z-C_x, B_x-A_y\rangle \times \langle dx,dy,dz \rangle \\ 
&= \langle (A_z-C_x)dz-(B_x-A_y)dy, \ (B_x-A_y)dx-(C_y-B_z)dz, \\ &\qquad (C_y-B_z)dy-(A_z-C_x)dx \rangle  
\end{align}
Well, if I made an error, I don't see it at present. The calculation above does not support the identity claimed. It has the right signs, but, the differentials and partial derivatives need to be swapped on six terms. I hope someone else sheds further light on this.

Comment: I'm glad the supper was delicious :D

That looked very close to what we wanted to show, so I tried to play around some bit... and I think I've found the correct expression... I'll post it as an answer now!

Comment: False alarm, I made an error. If only I knew how to interpret $\mathbf{e}_i (\partial_i F_j) \mathrm{dx}_j$ , maybe I could patch up something sensible!

Comment: @SchlomoSteinbergerstein in my current notation $e_1 = \langle 1,0,0 \rangle$.

Comment: I understand your notation, no worries, I just used this one to make the comment short. But it's not a matter of notation, I was playing around with some terms in the formula and I can identify every term in the result as some combination of $\nabla$ and $\mathbf{F}$ and $\mathbf{dr}$ except that one, $\mathbf{e}_i (\partial_i F_j) \mathrm{dx}_j$. And I changed from using P to F, my bad!

Comment: Well if you start with $[\nabla\cdot\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{r})] \mathbf{dr} + [\nabla\times\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{r})]\times\mathbf{dr}$, you get $\mathrm{d}\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{r}) + \langle B_y dx + C_z dx - C_x dz - B_x dy, A_xdy + C_z dy - A_y dx - C_y dz, A_x dz + B_y dz - B_z dy - A_z dx \rangle$.  So unless you can prove that second term is always zero, this identity is false.

Comment: @Bye_World yes, this in my conclusion as well, in the absence of additional data or context the identity is false.